# Run many observables at once in rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to run 3 observables and set the result to a recyclerview adapter. Is there a better way to run many observables at once. I've 3 observables like this and I'm running them individually. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Observable<AudioItems> observableTrend = audioModel.getTrendingMusic("all-audios",userId);
    Observable<AudioItems> observableTop = audioModel.getTrendingMusic("top-audios",userId);
    Observable<AudioItems> observableRecent = audioModel.getTrendingMusic("recent-audios",userId);
    observableTrend.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AudioItems>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AudioItems audioItems) {
                    recyclerViewTrending.setAdapter(new AudiosRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), audioItems.getAudios(), loginFlag));

                }

            });

    observableTop.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AudioItems>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AudioItems audioItems) {
                    recyclerViewTop.setAdapter(new AudiosRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), audioItems.getAudios(), loginFlag));

                }

            });

    observableRecent.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AudioItems>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AudioItems audioItems) {
                    recyclerViewRecent.setAdapter(new AudiosRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), audioItems.getAudios(), loginFlag));

                }

            });
```

Comment: You already kind of running them at once, i.e. each call to subscribe is not blocking, in your example. You could've merged or combined your observables into one big observable, but the fact that all of them require different treatment in the end interferes with this intention.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Zip or merge

That will throw the three observables.

Zip Observables:

```
@Test
public void testZip() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Observable.zip(obString(), obString1(), obString2(), (s, s2, s3) -> s.concat(s2)
                                                                         .concat(s3))
              .subscribe(result -> showResult("Sync:", start, result));
}


public void showResult(String transactionType, long start, String result) {
    System.out.println(result + " " +
                               transactionType + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

public Observable<String> obString() {
    return Observable.just("")
                     .map(val -> "Hello");
}
```

Merge Observables:

```
@Test
public void testMerge() {
    Observable.merge(obPerson(), obPerson1())
              .subscribe(result -> showResult(result.toString()));
}

private void showResult(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(++count);
}

public Observable<Person> obPerson() {
    return Observable.just(new Person("John", 34, null));
}

public Observable<Person> obPerson1() {
    return Observable.just(new Person(null, 25, "male"));
}
```